# Disable input on the form

Tags: html, css

I intend to disable form inputs. I know that `disabled` or `readonly` does this process. I intend to use `readonly` on the form.

I'll post the code and then explain the problem:

```css
@import url(https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto);
body,
input,
select,
textarea,
body * {
  font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body::after,
body::before,
input::after,
input::before,
select::after,
select::before,
textarea::after,
textarea::before,
body *::after,
body *::before {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.form-radio,
.form-group {
  position: relative;
}

.form-inline>.form-group,
.form-inline>.btn {
  display: inline-block;
  margin-bottom: 0;
}

.form-group input {
  height: 1.9rem;
}

.form-group .control-label {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0.25rem;
  pointer-events: none;
  padding-left: 0.125rem;
  z-index: 1;
  color: #3a3a3a;
  font-size: 1rem;
  font-weight: normal;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.28s ease;
  transition: all 0.28s ease;
}

.form-group .bar {
  position: relative;
  border-bottom: 0.0625rem solid #999;
  display: block;
}

.form-group .bar::before {
  content: '';
  height: 0.125rem;
  width: 0;
  left: 50%;
  bottom: -0.0625rem;
  position: absolute;
  background: #337ab7;
  -webkit-transition: left 0.28s ease, width 0.28s ease;
  transition: left 0.28s ease, width 0.28s ease;
  z-index: 2;
}

.form-group input,
.form-group textarea {
  display: block;
  background: none;
  padding: 0.125rem 0.125rem 0.0625rem;
  font-size: 1rem;
  border-width: 0;
  border-color: transparent;
  line-height: 1.9;
  width: 100%;
  color: transparent;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.28s ease;
  transition: all 0.28s ease;
  box-shadow: none;
}

.form-group select,
.form-group input:focus,
.form-group input:valid,
.form-group input.form-file,
.form-group input.has-value,
.form-group textarea:focus,
.form-group textarea:valid,
.form-group textarea.form-file,
.form-group textarea.has-value {
  color: #333;
}

.form-group select~.control-label,
.form-group input:focus~.control-label,
.form-group input:valid~.control-label,
.form-group input.form-file~.control-label,
.form-group input.has-value~.control-label,
.form-group textarea:focus~.control-label,
.form-group textarea:valid~.control-label,
.form-group textarea.form-file~.control-label,
.form-group textarea.has-value~.control-label {
  font-size: 0.8rem;
  color: #3a3a3a;
  top: -1rem;
  left: 0;
}

.form-group select:focus,
.form-group input:focus,
.form-group textarea:focus {
  outline: none;
}

.form-group select:focus~.control-label,
.form-group input:focus~.control-label,
.form-group textarea:focus~.control-label {
  color: #337ab7;
}

.form-group select:focus~.bar::before,
.form-group input:focus~.bar::before,
.form-group textarea:focus~.bar::before {
  width: 100%;
  left: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<form class="text-center border border-light largura limp6" action="#!">

  <div class="h4 mb-4">CONSULTAR PEDIDO DE MANUTENÇÃO</div>
  <div style="clear:both;"></div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4 col-xs-4">
      <div class="form-group">
        <input type="text" id="Pedi" name="Pedi" value="teste" readonly="true">
        <label for="Pedi" class="control-label">Pedido</label><i class="bar"></i>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</form>
```

The problem is in the CSS and I can't find it. The problem is that when I put `readonly = "true"` in the input, the value of that input is only visible if I click on the input and I want it to always be visible

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that there are CSS rules for your `<input>` and `<label>` which are only applied in the `:focus` pseudo-class, and it sounds like you want them applied by default without focusing on the element.  The relevant style rules appear to be:

for the `<label>`:

```
font-size: 0.8rem;
color: #3a3a3a;
top: -1rem;
left: 0;
```

and for the `<input>`:

```
color: #333;
```

Just add those to the CSS rules targeting those elements without the `:focus` pseudo-class:

```css
@import url(https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto);
body,
input,
select,
textarea,
body * {
  font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
body::after, body::before,
input::after,
input::before,
select::after,
select::before,
textarea::after,
textarea::before,
body *::after,
body *::before {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.form-radio,
.form-group {
  position: relative;

}

.form-inline > .form-group,
.form-inline > .btn {
  display: inline-block;
  margin-bottom: 0;
}

.form-group input {
  height: 1.9rem;
}

.form-group .control-label {
  position: absolute;
  pointer-events: none;
  padding-left: 0.125rem;
  z-index: 1;
  font-weight: normal;

  /* right here */
  font-size: 0.8rem;
  color: #3a3a3a;
  top: -1rem;
  left: 0;
}

.form-group .bar {
  position: relative;
  border-bottom: 0.0625rem solid #999;
  display: block;
}
.form-group .bar::before {
  content: '';
  height: 0.125rem;
  width: 0;
  left: 50%;
  bottom: -0.0625rem;
  position: absolute;
  background: #337ab7;
  -webkit-transition: left 0.28s ease, width 0.28s ease;
  transition: left 0.28s ease, width 0.28s ease;
  z-index: 2;
}
.form-group input,
.form-group textarea {
  display: block;
  background: none;
  padding: 0.125rem 0.125rem 0.0625rem;
  font-size: 1rem;
  border-width: 0;
  border-color: transparent;
  line-height: 1.9;
  width: 100%;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.28s ease;
  transition: all 0.28s ease;
  box-shadow: none;

  /* and here */
  color: #333;
}

.form-group select,
.form-group input:focus,
.form-group input:valid,
.form-group input.form-file,
.form-group input.has-value,
.form-group textarea:focus,
.form-group textarea:valid,
.form-group textarea.form-file,
.form-group textarea.has-value {
  color: #333;
}
.form-group select ~ .control-label,
.form-group input:focus ~ .control-label,
.form-group input:valid ~ .control-label,
.form-group input.form-file ~ .control-label,
.form-group input.has-value ~ .control-label,
.form-group textarea:focus ~ .control-label,
.form-group textarea:valid ~ .control-label,
.form-group textarea.form-file ~ .control-label,
.form-group textarea.has-value ~ .control-label {
  font-size: 0.8rem;
  color: #3a3a3a;
  top: -1rem;
  left: 0;
}
.form-group select:focus,
.form-group input:focus,
.form-group textarea:focus {
  outline: none;
}
.form-group select:focus ~ .control-label,
.form-group input:focus ~ .control-label,
.form-group textarea:focus ~ .control-label {
  color: #337ab7;
}
.form-group select:focus ~ .bar::before,
.form-group input:focus ~ .bar::before,
.form-group textarea:focus ~ .bar::before {
  width: 100%;
  left: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<form class="text-center border border-light largura limp6" action="#!">

     <div class="h4 mb-4">CONSULTAR PEDIDO DE MANUTENÇÃO</div>
                       <div style="clear:both;"></div>
                        <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-md-4 col-xs-4">
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <input type="text" id="Pedi" name="Pedi" value="teste" readonly="true">
                                <label for="Pedi" class="control-label">Pedido</label><i class="bar"></i>
                            </div>
                        </div>
          </div>
</form>
```

(Note: I assume the overlap between the `<label>` and the `<div>` with title text doesn't happen in your full code and is just a side-effect of this example.  Otherwise if the `<label>` wasn't meant to be visible at all then simply remove it of course.)